# Help proving improper integral converges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

The problem we are given is: Let $f$ be differentiable and nonzero on [1,$\infty$). If $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)})$ exists in $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and is less than $-1$, show that $\int_1^{\infty} f$ converges.

We are given the hint to consider $\frac{xf(x)}{\int_1^x f(x)}$ as $x\to\infty$.

Despite this hint, I am at a lost for where to begin. I tried applying the Limit Comparison Test to no avail. Can anyone give me an idea of where to begin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Since $f$ is differentiable (hence, continuous) and non-zero, either $f(x) > 0$ or $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [1,\infty)$. If $\int_1^\infty f$ fails to converge, either $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x f(t) \, dt = +\infty \text{   or  } \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x f(t) \, dt = -\infty$$

Apply L'Hopital's rule to obtain

$$\tag{*}\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{xf(x)}{\int_1 ^x f(t) \, dt} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x) + xf'(x)}{f(x)} = 1 + \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}  < 0$$

and find a contradiction by showing the LHS of (*) must be positive.

Comment: The phrase non-zero applies to $f'$ or $f$? Actually I was thinking about applying to $f$, and struggling with the result.

Comment: @user284331: The statement is $f$ is nonzero -- an important assumption since it appears in the denominator of $xf'/f$.  The limit using L'Hopital can be shown to be negative -- leading to the ultimate contradiction.

Comment: I still fail to see the point. And one thing, why must $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}xf(x)=\infty$, this is needed before doing L'Hopital.

Comment: @user28331:  Added to answer.  You only need the denominator to go to $\pm \infty$ to apply L'Hopital's rule.  It applies to the case $0/0$ or anything$/\infty$.

Comment: So if $f(x)$ is negative (positive) on $[1,\infty)$, then $\int_1^{\infty}f(t)dt$ must also be negative (positive)?

Comment: @Chubwagon: Yes - that is correct and helps complete the answer.

Comment: L'hopital for anything$/\infty $? Never heard of that..

Comment: I was not the down voter. I said that I have never heard of that to get some reference from you. I already looked it up and saw nothing about it. So could you please send me some link?

Comment: @Shashi:  Apologies. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2136053/148510

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I increased the range of my knowledge. +1

Comment: @Shashi: You're welcome.  This is not well known but it comes up here frequently.  I'll look for a another reference.

Comment: @Shashi: See General Proof (case 2) in Wikepedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: Yes I see it. I only read the first sentences. My bad! Thanks again!